# Checking if a user is connected to the network in android

Tags: android, crash, android-internet

In my main activity i have

```
 if (isNetworkAvailable() == true) {
        Log.i("testing", "available");

    } else {
        Log.i("test", "unaivalibale");
    }
```

Then below i have the method as

```
  private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
            = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

I have also set

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

In the manifest and yet when i run tha application it always stops, killing the application what is wrong

Comment: Show the logcat output.

Comment: The error is caused by `Context`, see my solution for a proper validation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check internet access on Android? InetAddress never times out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddress-never-times-out)

Comment: No its not check my question properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a class and add method properly:

```
public class ConnectivityStatus extends ContextWrapper{
public ConnectivityStatus(Context base) {
    super(base);
}

public static boolean isConnected(Context context){

    ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo connection = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (connection != null && connection.isConnectedOrConnecting()){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
 }
}
```

Get status, in Activity where you using as:

```
if(!ConnectivityStatus.isConnected(your_class_name.this)){
            //not connected
}else {
            //connected
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*********************************************************
 * NetworkStatus helps us to check the Internet connection 
 * state of our handheld device.**************************
 ********************************************************/
package com.mynetwork.network;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;


/**
 * @author Aashutosh
 *
 */
public class NetworkStatus {

    private static NetworkStatus instance = new NetworkStatus();
    static Context context;
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager;
    NetworkInfo wifiInfo, mobileInfo;
    boolean connected = false;

    public static NetworkStatus getInstance(Context ctx) {
        context = ctx;
        return instance;
    }

    public boolean isOnline(Context con) {
        try {
            connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) con.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            connected = networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isAvailable() && networkInfo.isConnected();
            return connected;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(context,"Check Connectivity Exception: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.v("connectivity", e.toString());
        }
        return connected;
    }

    /**
     * Checking for all possible Internet providers
     **/
    public boolean isConnectedToInternet(){
        connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivityManager != null){
            NetworkInfo[] info = connectivityManager.getAllNetworkInfo();
            if (info != null){
                for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++){
                    if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED){
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```